# On aes_string(), factor() and Rstudio's Shiny Package

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, aesthetics

When I run the following code:

```
  graph <- ggplot(data = graphData, aes_string(x = input$variable1, y = input$variable1))
  graph <- graph + geom_point( aes_string(colour=input$groupVariable) )
```

I get the following graph:
[image]

Which is problematic because it's not grouped by distinct colors, but rather with shades of blue.

I want this:

[image]

I tried to use `factor()` as in the following:

```
  graph <- ggplot(data = graphData, aes_string(x = input$variable1, y = input$variable2))
  graph <- graph + geom_point( aes_string(colour=factor(input$groupVariable) ) )
```

But that just gives me this:

[image]

What should I do to get the graph as in the middle image?

**Note** *input* is the channel through which Rstudio's Shiny package communicates between it's ui.R and server.R scripts.

Comment: @TheTime I also tried that but it doesn't work. It will say that the middle-man variable we created to store the factor at ahead of time cannot be found.

Comment: @TheTime I'm not sure I follow, could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

graphData[,input$groupVariable] <- factor(graphData[,input$groupVariable])

ggplot(graphData, aes_string(x=input$variable1, y=input$variable2, color=input$groupVariable)) + geom_point()
})
```

Comment: I have to comment on old answers, but can you add some details on why your code is correct?