# Reactive DateRangeInput for Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm teaching myself Shiny and I am stuck on my ggplot2 graph not being able to use the reactive dateRangeInput as my x-axis. I have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to use my data frame to grab the min, max values for date range input instead of having to hardcode them in so that when I add more tweets to the data frame I don't have to hardcode the values each time?
2. I am getting the error: `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (33108): x, y` when I try to use input$date as my aes(x = input$date...

```html
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

tweets <- read.csv(file.choose())
colnames(tweets)[1] <- "Content"
tweets <- separate(tweets, created_at, c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ")
tweets$Date <-as.Date(tweets$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(inputId = "date", 
              strong("Date Range"),
              start = "2009-05-04", end = "2018-02-28",
              min = "2009-05-04", max ="2018-02-28" ),
  plotOutput("Graph")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(tweets, aes(x = input$date, y = count)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
      #scale_y_continuous(name = "Retweet Count", limits = c(0,370000), breaks=seq(0,370000,10000)) +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Pete900's answer summarizes the use of `updateDateRangeInput` well, for further information you can refer to [this part](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateDateRangeInput.html) of the shiny documentation.

About your second problem: `input$date` will return a vector of length 2 with the first element beeing the lower and the second being the upper part of the selected range. You will most likely not use this directly as x-aesthetics but rather subset your data with this and then plot the newly subsettet data. You can e.g. write

```
library(dpylr) # alternatevly library(tidyverse)
newtweets <- reactive({
filter(tweets, between(date ,input$date[1], input$date[2]))
})
```

then, in your ggplot, use `newtweets()` as your data.

**Update**
The functions `filter` and `between()` (which is a shortcut for x is greater than ... and lesser then ...) come fromt the package `dplyr`, which is great for working with dataframes and part of a collection of packages that play very nicely with each other called `tidyverse` (see [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/)).

When you refer to the newly created reactive object `newtweets()`, make sure to not forget the paranthesis because it is now a function call, that enables shiny to update the dataframe should the input change.

**Update**

A full working example in which I create some artificial data:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# tweets <- read.csv(file.choose())

st <- ymd("2009-05-01")
en <- ymd("2018-02-28")
dates <- seq.Date(from = st, to = en, by = 1)
tweets <- tibble(date = dates, count = rnorm(length(dates), mean = 5, sd = 3))


ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput(inputId = "date",
                   strong("Date Range"),
                   start = "2009-05-04", end = "2018-02-28",
                   min = "2009-05-04", max ="2018-02-28" ),
    plotOutput("Graph")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    newtweets <- reactive({
        filter(tweets, between(date ,input$date[1], input$date[2]))
    })

    output$Graph <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(newtweets(), aes(x = date, y = count)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
            #scale_y_continuous(name = "Retweet Count", limits = c(0,370000), breaks=seq(0,370000,10000)) +
            theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ok so filter will find the rows where the min, max values are true and between will grab everything in between. Will it grab all the other columns in the df? And so if I'm understanding this correctly I can use newtweets as the df to plot in the ggplot and that will be reactive now?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not include the packages I use and will update my answer.

Comment: I get the error when I add your code in `Warning: Error in filter_impl: Evaluation error: object 'input' not found.`

Comment: so is newtweets() the new x axis or the new df to plot in ggplot?

Comment: It will be your new data / dataframe to put in the plot. The reactive function I made must be inside the server function, maybe the error comes from putting it elsewhere. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html for more information.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately now I get this error: `Error in filter_impl: Evaluation error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=closure; target=double]..` I appreciate the help so far but if you have any suggestions on how to fix this error I would be grateful.

Comment: can you provide a repex ( a minimal reproducible example, to make it easy for people to reproduce your error and then fix it)? As we don't have your csv file it is considered good practive to incluce minimal example data in the form of code. The r package reprex can help you witht this: https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex

Comment: See the update for a working examples of how it should look in your code.

Comment: What if we made the limits of `scale_x_date` , the `input$date[1]` & `input$date[2]` ? Then the plot would re-render when these dates changed. Or is it better practice to make the data set reactive?

Comment: This would also work. Sometimes you want to have other things that depend on the same data, like e.g. a download button for the subset of data shown on the plot. If this is a requirement or you think it might be a requirement in the future, it is the better option to make the data itself reactive.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question you can use `updateDateRangeInput` see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateDateRangeInput.html). So you would find your min and max dates in tweets outside of the `server` function then pass them to the input. Make sure to add `session` to your function:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

   observe({
    updateDateRangeInput(session, "date", min = myMinDate, max = myMaxDate)
   })
}
```

For the second question you need to use `aes_string` to pass variables to ggplot, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057280/on-aes-string-factor-and-rstudios-shiny-package).

Comment: Ok so will the `aes_string` pull the date data from the tweets df and plot based on that or will it take the values from my min, max values, fill in the rest and plot based on matching up those dates to the date column in the tweets df? Also will I be able to plot the y axis from the tweets df or another new df?

Comment: See @Jannik Buhr's answer for details on that.